Can I remove this beam inside my chimney?
Breaking down my chimney which is in the center of the house and I find this beam that was covered up by bricks. The goal was to increase the size of my kitchen by removing the chimney space but now with this column in the way I can’t. It goes up from the basement all the way to the attic. Is this safe to remove? Any ideas on how to deal with this?
https://imgur.com/a/wxJ96Mg

Most likely no.  You may get an engineer to find the real reason, but generally if something starts at the basement and goes all the way to the attic it is supporting some vital structural elements.

It sure looks load bearing to me but then, I'm no structural engineer. You really should get one to check this out and nor rely on the internet.
